# unbindModel call in CakePhp. How does it work?

Tags: php, cakephp

How does unbindModel happen in cake?

```
$this->User->unbindModel(array('hasAndBelongsToMany' => array('Friend')));
```

I wrote this in the beginning of a function. But still it queries the 'Friend' model. There was a call to paginate() in the middle of the function. So I thought the paginator might be generating the queries.

I did added an unbindModel call just before paginate and it now works.

```
$this->User->unbindModel(array('hasAndBelongsToMany' => array('Friend')));
$user = $this->paginate("User", array("User.first_name LIKE" => $user["User"]["first_name"]));
```

Does unbindModel unbind every query? or does it unbind during the entire function call?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[From the manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html):

> Removing or adding associations using bind- and unbindModel() only works for **the next model operation** unless the second parameter has been set to `false`. If the second parameter has been set to `false`, the bind remains in place for the remainder of the request.

In other words, after you `paginate()` or `find()` or do anything else with the model, the unbinding will be reversed.

Comment: in this case is it good practice to unbind like this?? `unset($this->User->hasAndBelongsToMany['Friend])`

Comment: @RSK That would either do nothing, or break things horribly. I wouldn't want to try either way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707859/cakephp-validating-a-login-form-using-validate-array can u plz answer for this

Comment: @RSK No, because I don't see any need to validate login information. The login is either correct or it isn't, giving any more details only helps potential attackers. I have written about this here before somewhere, but can't find it right now.

Comment: For future visitors, this shouldn't be the accepted answer - the `paginate()` function internally queries twice (as darkcode points out below, once to retrieve the data, and once to retrieve the count) so you will get very strange results by calling `paginate()` after an `unbindModel()` without the persist option set to `true`.

Answer (score 4):

Well, in my experience with unbinds, I can say Paginate always do 2 querys one for count the total and the second for the result array

unbind destroy just once time the relation and yea you need extend this rule to destroy two or more times so you need to set TRUE I guess to persist this rule:

```
$this->User->unbindModel(array('hasAndBelongsToMany' => array('Friend')), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$this->Leader->find('all');

// Let's remove the hasMany...
$this->Leader->unbindModel(
    array('hasMany' => array('Follower'))
);

// Now using a find function will return
// Leaders, with no Followers
$this->Leader->find('all');

// NOTE: unbindModel only affects the very next
// find function. An additional find call will use
// the configured association information.

// We've already used find('all') after unbindModel(),
// so this will fetch Leaders with associated
// Followers once again...
$this->Leader->find('all');
```