# Can not retrieve multiple records from the database in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I am working with 2.6.1 version of CakePHP. I have created one controller named as AndroidController.php and that looks like

```
<?php
class AndroidController extends AppController {

public function survey_question()
{
    Configure::write('debug', '2');
    $survey_id = $_REQUEST['survey_id'];
    $this->layout = "";
    //$condition = "Question.survey_id = '".$survey_id."'";
    $info = $this->Question->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
                    "Question.survey_id" => $survey_id  /*dont use array() */
            )
        ));
    echo json_encode($info);
    exit;
}
}
?>
```

So, it gives an error like

> Error: The action admin_survey_question is not defined in controller
>   AndroidController
>
> Error:Create AndroidController::admin_survey_question() in file: app/Controller/AndroidController.php.
>
> Note :My website url is
>   http://navyon.com/dev/mt/admin/android/survey_question?survey_id=2

So how can I resolve this?

Comment: You try "http://navyon.com/dev/mt/android/survey_question?survey_id=2". In url admin means it searches the admin function

Comment: @MathsRkBala i don't know why I used admin because In project they use admin then controller name then method.So I have use url as admin than controller than method.

Comment: You change "survey_question" into "admin_survey_question". Then your problem will be solved.

Comment: @MathsRkBala I have called this **http://navyon.com/dev/mt/android/admin_survey_question?survey_id=2** url than gives an error like **AndroidController::admin_survey_question() cannot be accessed directly.**

Comment: change action name `admin_survey_question` and call as you are calling `http://navyon.com/dev/mt/admin/android/survey_question?survey_id=2` earlier

Comment: @MohdSayeed So it gives an error as in question.

Comment: have you enabled admin prefix in core.php

Comment: In core.php near line no#155, `Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));`

Comment: @MohdSayeed I am new for CakePHP so please give me the path of care.php

Comment: Core path: `app/Config/core.php`

Comment: @MohdSayeed Its already define as **Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin','services'));**

Comment: Are you sure, you created action nameed `admin_survey_question`?

Comment: @MohdSayeed Yes, I have created admin_survey_question.

Comment: I can;t check its goes to user/login 
`http://navyon.com/dev/mt/android/admin_survey_question?survey_id=2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have enable `admin` routing for that action so your action should preceded `admin_` 
Then your action look like below:

```
<?php
class AndroidController extends AppController {

public function admin_survey_question() 
{
Configure::write('debug', '2');
$survey_id = $_REQUEST['survey_id'];
$this->layout = "";
//$condition = "Question.survey_id = '".$survey_id."'";
$info = $this->Question->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
                "Question.survey_id" => $survey_id  /*dont use array()      */
        )
    ));
echo json_encode($info);
exit;
 }
}
?>
```

If you don't want enable `admin` routing for that action then remove admin from `url` and access like this :

```
http://navyon.com/dev/mt/android/survey_question?survey_id=2
```

Comment: It gives an error like **Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object**

Comment: just write `$this->loadModel('Question');` within the action.Its means you have not loaded model.Try to learn more about cakephp http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models.html :)

Comment: like `public function admin_survey_question() 
{ 
$this->loadModel('Question');
.....`

Comment: Thanks Its working now. But it also return other table record.

Comment: you can unbind the other model , if it works then accept the answer.

Comment: Yes but in some function they use so how can unbind other model in this function?

Comment: Try this to unbind model on controller http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587224/unbindmodel-call-in-cakephp-how-does-it-work

Comment: When I used **http://navyon.com/dev/mt/android/survey_question?survey_id=2** this link then I have to login in my site then i can use it so what should I have to to access direct this api?

Comment: make this action permission free.